# WPF program hangs on certain Dell laptops

Tags: c#, wpf, freeze

I have a WPF program that tends to hang for 5-10 seconds on a few of the Dell laptops we have in our facility. They are the same model of laptop. The spot where it hangs, the program is querying the database using EF6. The query comes back in about 50ms. Then the program just hangs. Before I realised that this was specific to this laptop I put the methods in a background worker to make the program seem more fluid. The background worker didn't actually work because the process ran too fast and wasn't the issue. However, if I sleep the thread for 100ms my busy indicator actually comes up and the 5-10 second lag is gone.

Could anyone shed some light on what specifically about the laptop could be the issue? I do have the latest Dell graphics driver installed and I also manually installed the latest graphics driver from Intel.

Also in both of the areas where the program hangs I am filling a Grid View. If I change the Grid View to a Combo Box then my lag will go away as well.
I also changed the Grid View to a list box to see if that would make a difference and it did not, the 5-10 second lag was still an issue. The amount of items going into the collection is from 10 to 150

Comment: Only on Dell laptops ?  or there is some specs change as well ?

Comment: One possibility I always try to eliminate first is the Tablet PC Input Service.  It’s caused plenty of odd WPF quirks on _just some machines_ (those w/ pen or touch input).  Disable it, then run your app.  See if I that helps.  If not, it’s one item off the checklist :).

Comment: Also, check that you’ve enabled virtualization for your grid views.  I’m not sure why it’d be enabled by default on on machine and not another, but hey.

Comment: Did you profile this exact place on both good/bad machines?

Comment: _"Could anyone shed some light on what specifically about the laptop could be the issue?"_ -- if that's your question, it puts your post squarely in the **off-topic** category, as that's clearly a question about **general computing hardware and software**. If your question is at all to do with programming, you will need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem (even if it does so reliably only on certain Dell laptops).